# how to add,update,delete record in UITableView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

how to add , update , delete record in UITableView?

Answer (score 2):

iOS follows the MVC paradigm pretty strictly. `UITableView` doesn't manage any data by itself—it gets all the data it displays by requesting it from its delegate and data source objects. For more information on that, check out the `UITableView` documentation, or one of the quick-start guides, or, hell, Google “UITableView tutorial”.

Answer (score 1):

you need to make database in which you insert,delete and update data and according to this you need to reflect changes to your table view.

Answer (score 1):

Without a much more specific question, it's hard to help. You should consider reading the [UITableView class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [UITableViewDataSource protocol reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). The data source specifies what appears in the table view, and the table view class itself has a couple of helpful methods:

```
- (void)insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
- (void)deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
```